# Power mode Ubuntu 23.04 (lobster)

Tags: battery

Whenever i check my laptop battery mode is on power saver mode. I change it performance or balanced then after several minutes it goes back to power saver mode even battery is 100% or plugged in to charger. So basically it means the function in GUI is not working or is it commonly found issue on Linux?